# Problem in Silverlight smooth streaming in Chrome

Tags: silverlight, streaming, smoothing

Sometimes i'm getting a problem in google chrome when i try to play a smooth streaming video.
Can someone please test this link:

http://bizup.cloudapp.net/post/136

Thanks,
João

Answer (score 0):

i've found the solution:

http://smf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=225581

not perfect, but actually works.